# enterScene event does not triggered

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am trying to create a game using gyroscope and I am facing a very strange problem. I have the following two scene's

[image]

[image]

I want when the ball in the first scene collide with the door to move to the second scene.
When the ball move slowly and collide with the door everything works fine and the next scene starts normaly, but if the ball in the first scene move very fast and collide with the door with great force the next scene starts frοsted, it seems like the enterscene event is not triggered. Any Idea?

My code:

**Scene1:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- scene1.lua
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

system.setIdleTimer( false )

local physics = require "physics"
local physicsData = (require "myphysics").physicsData(1.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF  IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local displayTime,background,ball,maze,maze2,borders,exitscn
local startTime=0
local levelTime = 20

local function onGyroscopeDataReceived( event )
    local deltaRadiansX = event.xRotation * event.deltaTime
    local deltaDegreesX = deltaRadiansX * (180 / math.pi)
    local deltaRadiansY = event.yRotation * event.deltaTime
    local deltaDegreesY = deltaRadiansY * (180 / math.pi)
    ball:applyForce( -deltaDegreesX*6, -deltaDegreesY*6, ball.x, ball.y )
end



function nextScene()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "loadscene2")
end

local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
       if(event.object1.name=="exitscn" or event.object2.name=="exitscn") then
            timer.performWithDelay ( 500, nextScene )
        end 
    end

end

local function gameOver()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 300)
end

local function checkTime(event)
  local now = os.time()
  displayTime.text = levelTime - (now - startTime)
  if ( levelTime - (now - startTime)==0) then
    gameOver()
  end
end





-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    physics.start(); 
    physics.setGravity( 0,0 )

    displayTime = display.newText(levelTime, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20)
    displayTime.isVisible=false

    background=display.newImage("bcklevel1.png")
    background.x=display.contentCenterX
    background.y=display.contentCenterY

    ball=display.newImage("ball1.png")
    ball.x=30
    ball.y=display.contentCenterY
    ball.name="ball"

    maze=display.newImage( "maze1.png" )
    maze.x=display.contentCenterX
    maze.y=display.contentCenterY
    maze.name="maze"

    maze2=display.newImage( "maze1.png" )
    maze2.x=display.contentCenterX
    maze2.y=display.contentCenterY
    maze2.name="maze2"

    borders=display.newImage( "borders.png" )
    borders.x=display.contentCenterX
    borders.y=display.contentCenterY
    borders.name="borders"
    borders.alpha=0.1

    exitscn=display.newImage("exit.png")
    exitscn.x=display.contentWidth-30
    exitscn.y=display.contentCenterY
    exitscn.name="exitscn"

    physics.addBody (ball, "dynamic",physicsData:get("ball"))
    physics.addBody (maze, "static",physicsData:get("mazelevel1_1"))
    physics.addBody (maze2, "static",physicsData:get("mazelevel1_2"))
    physics.addBody (borders, "static",physicsData:get("borders"))
    physics.addBody (exitscn, "dynamic",physicsData:get("exitscn"))

    --ball:addEventListener ( "touch", nextScene )
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", checkTime)
    Runtime:addEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )

    screenGroup:insert( background )
    screenGroup:insert(displayTime)
    screenGroup:insert( ball )
    screenGroup:insert( maze )
    screenGroup:insert( maze2 )
    screenGroup:insert( borders )
    screenGroup:insert( exitscn )


    print( "\n1: createScene event")
end




-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )

    print( "1: enterScene event" )
    physics.start()

    startTime = os.time()
    displayTime.isVisible=true

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )
    physics.stop( )


    Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", checkTime )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )

    print( "((destroying scene 1's view))" )
    package.loaded[physics] = nil
    physics = nil
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

**Scene2:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- scene2.lua
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

system.setIdleTimer( false )

local physics = require "physics"
local physicsData = (require "myphysics").physicsData(1.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF  IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local displayTime,background,ball,maze,maze2,borders,exitscn
local startTime=0
local levelTime = 20

local function onGyroscopeDataReceived( event )
    local deltaRadiansX = event.xRotation * event.deltaTime
    local deltaDegreesX = deltaRadiansX * (180 / math.pi)
    local deltaRadiansY = event.yRotation * event.deltaTime
    local deltaDegreesY = deltaRadiansY * (180 / math.pi)
    ball:applyForce( -deltaDegreesX*6, -deltaDegreesY*6, ball.x, ball.y )
end

function nextScene()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 1000 )
end

local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
       if(event.object1.name=="exitscn" or event.object2.name=="exitscn") then
            timer.performWithDelay ( 500, nextScene )
        end 
    end

end

 local function gameOver()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 300)
end

local function checkTime(event)
  local now = os.time()
  displayTime.text = levelTime - (now - startTime)
  if ( levelTime - (now - startTime)==0) then
    gameOver()
  end
end





-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    physics.start(); 
    physics.setGravity( 0,0 )

    displayTime = display.newText(startTime, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20)
    displayTime.isVisible=false

    background=display.newImage("bcklevel1.png")
    background.x=display.contentCenterX
    background.y=display.contentCenterY

    ball=display.newImage("ball1.png")
    ball.x=30
    ball.y=display.contentCenterY
    ball.name="ball"

    maze=display.newImage( "maze2.png" )
    maze.x=display.contentCenterX
    maze.y=display.contentCenterY
    maze.name="maze"

    maze2=display.newImage( "maze2.png" )
    maze2.x=display.contentCenterX
    maze2.y=display.contentCenterY
    maze2.name="maze2"

    borders=display.newImage( "borders.png" )
    borders.x=display.contentCenterX
    borders.y=display.contentCenterY
    borders.name="borders"
    borders.alpha=0.1

    exitscn=display.newImage("exit.png")
    exitscn.x=display.contentWidth-30
    exitscn.y=display.contentCenterY
    exitscn.name="exitscn"

    physics.addBody (ball, "dynamic",physicsData:get("ball"))
    physics.addBody (maze, "static",physicsData:get("mazelevel2_1"))
    physics.addBody (maze2, "static",physicsData:get("mazelevel2_2"))
    physics.addBody (borders, "static",physicsData:get("borders"))
    physics.addBody (exitscn, "dynamic",physicsData:get("exitscn"))

    --ball:addEventListener ( "touch", nextScene )
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", checkTime)
    Runtime:addEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )

    screenGroup:insert( background )
    screenGroup:insert(displayTime)
    screenGroup:insert( ball )
    screenGroup:insert( maze )
    screenGroup:insert( maze2 )
    screenGroup:insert( borders )
    screenGroup:insert( exitscn )


    print( "\n1: createScene event")
end




-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )

    print( "1: enterScene event" )
    physics.start()
    startTime = os.time()
    displayTime.isVisible=true

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )
    physics.stop( )

    Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", checkTime )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "gyroscope", onGyroscopeDataReceived )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )

    print( "((destroying scene 2's view))" )
    package.loaded[physics] = nil
    physics = nil
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: The answer was meant as a comment. It was however too long to post in this field..

Comment: I think in your case, you can get a solution without collision detection. Just check 'if(ball.x >= door.x)' with a timer triggering in certain small intervals. This may help you if you want... :)

Comment: Is your nextScene() function getting called more than once? Try using a print message inside the function to double check it is only running once.

Answer (score 0):

In the second file, i bet there is something spooky about

```
function nextScene()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 1000 )
end

local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
       if(event.object1.name=="exitscn" or event.object2.name=="exitscn") then
            timer.performWithDelay ( 500, nextScene )
        end 
    end

end
```

first you delay with 500 ms and then an additional 1000 ms delays the transition to the next scene. Maybe you are aware of this, but you are not handling this transition the same way here as in the first file.

Answer (score 0):

I think code is proper. there is some problem of grouping things in enter scene and memory reload for storyboard scenes. Please try with below solutions:

1. I think you written whole code in create scene and this will call once a time for a storyboard scene. You should try to implement reusable code in enterScene and should use local group = self.view for enter scene objects.
2. You should try to refresh or release memory of current storyboard scene either on DOOR collision with ball OR from exit scene of current storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the collision event gets triggered more than once while you delay to call nextScene.

Try doing something like this:

```
local hasNextSceneEventHappened = false

local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
       -- Ignore the call if we have already collided for next level
       if(event.object1.name=="exitscn" or event.object2.name=="exitscn") then
            if (hasNextSceneEventHappened == true ) then return end
            hasNextSceneEventHappened = true
            timer.performWithDelay ( 500, nextScene )
       end 
    end
end
```

This code will ensure that you dont spam the goToScene() function and get undesired behavior.
I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

use a flag like `didGo`.
init this flag on your file body to `false` and write something like this:

```
-- body of your file:
local didGo = false

-- when you want to go to another scene
if ( not didGo) then
 didGo = true
 storyboard.gotoScene...
end
```